# confusion about recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

let us suppose that  we have following recurrence relation

$a_n-a_{n-1}=2*n$  where  $a_0=0$

as i know solution is following

$a_n=a_0+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 2n   $

which is the same  as
$a_n=2*\sum\limits_{i=1}^n n   $

but this term
$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n n=n^2$

therefore 
$a_n=2*n^2$

but youtube says that

[image]

and also  wolfram alpha says that solution is  $a_n=n*(n+1)$  how?

Comment: Your notation is confusing, and you have got the sum of integers formula wrong. $1+2=3=\frac {2\times 3}2$ and not $2^2=4$.

Comment: I used his notation,  and he made  mistake

Comment: On the Internet you also find pages claiming and actually *proving* that the Earth is flat. The image you show is an example of something you shouldn't trust to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two summations are correct,
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n i &= \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\
\sum_{i=1}^n n &= n \sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n(n) = n^2
\end{align}
For your recurrence relation, we have that at each iteration you extract a term of the form $2i$ as such
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a_n &= a_{n-1} + 2n\\ &= a_{n-2} + 2(n-1) + 2n\\ &= \vdots \\ &= a_{i} + 2(i+1) + \ldots + 2n
\end{split}
\end{equation}
For $i = 0$, we get
$$a_n = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n 2i = 0 + 2 \sum_{i=1}^n i = 2 \frac{n(n+1)}{2}=n(n+1)$$

Comment: now it is clear, but i think  he  also  use wrong notation because direct insertion gives us exactly $a_n=2*n^2 $

Comment: you are right. The reference you posted has a mistake in the second line, should be $2\sum_{i=1}^n i$ instead of $2\sum_{i=1}^n n$